# Filter the product list with data-price attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I am able to filter the product list on basis of store and brand in my code, but I'm not able to filter it with price range.

```
<div id="prod">
    <div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="1000" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="4300" data-store="JCPenny">Hill</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="1600" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="800" data-store="SuperMart">Hill</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="2300" data-store="SuperMart">Hill</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="800" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Andrew" />Andrew
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Hill" />Hill
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="JCPenny" />JCPenny
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="SuperMart" />SuperMart
    <input type="radio" name="range" class="price" id="0-ALL"/>All
    <input type="radio" name="range" class="price" id="0-2000"/>Rs.0-2000
    <input type="radio" name="range" class="price" id="2000-4000"/>Rs.2000-4000
    <input type="radio" name="range" class="price" id="4000-6000"/>Rs.4000-6000
    <input type="radio" name="range" class="price" id=">6000"/>Rs.>6000
</div>
```

Above is my `div` layout, below I'm highlighting my JavaScript for filtering logic which I have done for brand and store with my friends help

```
<script>
var a=$("input.brand");
var b=$("input.store");
var brand=new Array();
var store=new Array();
$("input[name=range]").change(function (e) {

alert("range");
    var toggle = this.checked;
    var range = this.value.split('-');
    var rangeFrom = parseInt(range[0]);
    var rangeTo = parseInt(range[1]);
    $(".container >div[data-price]").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // Check if category is active
        var categoryActive = $("#" + $this.data("brand")).prop("checked");
        // Get price as number
        var price = parseFloat($this.data('price'));
        // Toggle visibility based on category and price range
        $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo && categoryActive );
    });
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#prod >div').hide();
        if(this.className == "brand"){
            console.debug("brand checked");
            brand.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }else if(this.className == "store"){
            console.debug("store checked");
            store.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
        console.log(brand+","+store);
        displaydivs(brand,store);
    }else{
        $('#prod >div').show();
        if(this.className == "brand"){
            var index = brand.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
            if (index > -1) {
                brand.splice(index, 1);
            }       
        }else if(this.className == "store"){
            var index = store.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
            if (index > -1) {
                store.splice(index, 1);
            } 
        }
        displaydivs(brand,store);
    }     
});


function displaydivs(brand,store)
{
    $("#prod >div").hide();
    if(brand.length > 0 & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each(brand, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-store");
            var idx = store.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"][data-store="+data+"]").show();
          }            
      });  
        $.each(store, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-brand");
            var idx = brand.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+data+"][data-store="+value+"]").show();
          }            
      });
    }
    else if(brand.length > 0 & !(store.length > 0)){ 
        $.each( brand, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }
    else if(!(brand.length > 0) & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each( store, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }else{
        $("#prod >div").show();
    }
}
</script>
```

This code is working fine for store and brand both but I'm not able to code for price range filtering. Basically my requirement is as follows.

When I select suppose a brand from checkbox list say andrew, then I select a store like JCPenny and three divs will come because `data-brand=andrew` and `data-store=JCPenny` are present in only three divs collectively. Then if I select price range filter(2000-4000), then I should get only those divs in which data-brand is Andrew and data-store is JCPenny and price is from 2000 till 4000.

Please guide me how to do price filtering on this list.It will be a lot of help if sum body can help me out.

Comment: Use [data-price] as the selector.

Comment: not able to do it sir with range,can u help me with a small code snippet regarding this....Please

Comment: @C-link-Please help once u get on desktop or laptop.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.attr('data-store')`, try `.data('store')`

and follow the same pattern for all data attributes

Comment: i tried with .data('store'),but i m not able to write logic for data-price filteration.can u please help in code..

Comment: @Marco-Can u please help me out in price filteration of above scenario please.as i m quite weak in javascript.Thanks in advance sir...

Comment: Have a look at the edited post where i added script for price...please check i tried it but it didnt work.guyzz,help me please